# Chromecast from android doesn't use styled receiver

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, chromecast

I have implemented Chromecast on my website, using a `styled media receiver`.

It works great on desktop.

Although when I cast videos from my website from an android tablet, I guess that instead of using my Chromecast code, it uses Google Chrome's default implementation of Chromecast, therefore not using my `styled media receiver`, but the *generic media receiver* instead.

Is there any way to make sure my app uses my styled media receiver instead of the default one? I've seen this on a lot of other websites, but I've also noticed that Youtube has a custom one.

Is it just because Youtube belongs to Google and they have built something specific for it?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the media route selector knows about your app id:

```
mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
  .addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast("YOUR_APPLICATION_ID"))
  .build();
```

In addition, make sure when oyu launch your app, you include your app id:

```
Cast.CastApi.launchApplication(mApiClient, "YOUR_APPLICATION_ID", false)
```

Comment: No I'm not using any Android App. I'm casting from my website from android chrome

Comment: Then you cannot change where it goes, i.e. it will use the default receiver and you cannot change that.